# Task overrides task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-7.1

I have a task to fetch content from my server. The problem is, that sometimes a Task overrides the task before, so I get two times the same result.

My Code:

```
 Task<string> task = Server.GetText();
        string result = await task;
        if (result == "\n")
        {
            .....
        }
        else
        {
            string[] sarray = result.Split('|');

            App.MainList.Add(new etc.Text(sarray[0], sarray[1], sarray[2], sarray[3], sarray[4]));

            App.Number++;
        }
```

GetText():

```
public static async Task<string> GetText()
    {
        if (App.Number <= App.Total)
        {
            HttpClient http = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync(queryuri + "?w=" + App.Number.ToString());
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        else
        {
            App.Number = 1;
            HttpClient http = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync(queryuri + "?w=" + App.Number.ToString());
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

    }
```

Comment: You haven't given us nearly enough context to go on here. We have no idea what `Server.GetText()` does, or how you're diagnosing this. You'll need to clarify it a lot before we can help you.

Comment: What do you mean "it's overriding the old result"; I still believe this is caused by re-entry (you're incrementing App.Number only after you get the text from the server, so a user pressing the button twice before the server responds would start two identical queries that would both return, but when they return, App.Number would no longer have the expected value)

Comment: I mean with overwritting the old result, that in the end i have to excact entries. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean with overwritting the old result, that in the end i have to excact entries. How can I solve the problem?

When the first method enters (presumably because of a user button press) you're calling `GetText()` using `await`; Let's assume `App.Number` is `1` when you first do this. Because of the `await` execution is suspended right there until `GetText()` returns, but your GUI is not! Let's assume the user presses the same button again. `GetText()` will again be called and `App.Number` will still be `1` because the first `GetText()` hasn't yet returned. Since the query is built based on `App.Number` then you're obviously going to get two identical results.

When the first `GetText()` returns you're going to increment `App.Number` so it's now `2`; When the second `GetText()` returns the `App.Number` gets implemented once more! You're not only getting the result for `App.Number==1` twice, you're going to complitely skip the result for `App.Number==2`!

Depending on what the meaning of those numbers is, you'd have multiple solutions: Increment `App.Number` before you call `GetText()` AND pass the number as a parameter, make the method non-re-entrant, whatever works for you. If for example there's some meaning in the order of the request, then the best option is to disable the button because HTTP requests sent in parallel aren't guaranteed to complete in the order they were started. For example your `GetText(2)` could easily return before `GetText(1)`; It's also possible that `GetText(n)` might never return because of some error.

You now know why you're seeing what you're seeing, but I can't suggest a solution because I don't actually know what the correct behavior should be. That's up to you!

Comment: it is no Problem if the user hits the button before, but it should not override the old result

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one question left: The order doesn't mind, as long as no number is skipped or twice. I really don't like to make the button not clickable. Should I try then the solution with the Parameter?

Comment: Simplest solution: Move the App.Number<App.Total into the first method and pass the "Number" as a parameter to the GetText method; Make sure you increment App.Number before calling "await GetText()"; That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a threading problem.  I'm assuming App.Number starts at 1, and App.Total is 4, but I think it'd happen with any value where App.Number <= App.Total.

The initial code is triggered on two different threads, both of which start running Server.GetText(), and hit the if statement, choose the first branch, build the URL and issue the request with w=1.  Since this call takes time, and the App.Number increment is *after* the response comes back, I think that is what is causing your issue.

I think your issue is that you need to update App.Number as soon as you read it to build the URL (plus hold a lock while reading/incrementing it so that you don't still have a race condition).

Comment: what is the best way to do it?